# Setting up map in typescript for new values fails

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to set the map like below:

```
 this.finance['assets']['realEstate'] = {
          "name":"Primary Home",
          "monthlyMortgage": 0
        }
```

Where it is defined as below

```
export class Finance {
   assets:any 

   constructor(){
     this.assets = { 
      "dummy": true
     }
   }
}
```

So basically, i am hoping to create an embedded map with my code and this fails in trying to initialize this way in typescript.

any idea how to fix it

Comment: ① Please [edit] the question to explicitly describe how it fails (e.g., if you see an error, please say what it is and which line of code causes) and how others can demonstrate it for themselves (by providing a [mre] that, at the least, introduces where `this.finance` comes from). ② Is there a reason you're using `any` for the type of `assets` instead of the actual expected type, whatever it is?  The `any` type is intentionally unsound and lets you do all kinds of unsafe things, which might be part of the reason why you're running into this problem.